# D3.js (or similar) Overlapping Bar Chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using D3.js Is there an option to overlay one bar over another?

I need two independent columns to indicate start and end time (x axis) against a count (y axis). I want BOTH columns to be overlaid over each other (similar start time e.g x1=8:45am, x2=10:05, and same end times. y1=90, y2=108), both columns will have transparency around 0.5, so each column can be seen over the common time/count range.

A similar example using Highcharts:

http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/q8Udk/

```
// This page provides an example in highcharts
{ I need same for D3}
```

I need to create a chart where

- Column width dependant on (end_time - start_time)
- Column x origin is dependant on start time
- Column height dependant on y value
- The columns need opacity less than 1.

Answer (score 13):

`d3.js` requires you to *explicitly* place your bars at coordinates, so, you can put your bars where ever you like:

```
  // create a group for your overlapped bars
  var g = svg.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")

  // place the first bar  
  g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar1")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter) + 10; // center it
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 20) // make it slimmer
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.col1);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.col1);
    });

  // place the second bar on top of it
  g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar2")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.col2);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.col2);
    });
```

Here's a quick [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wfOx8615PnZh2CST301F?p=preview).

[image]

**EDITS**

To add in time, you have to make a number of changes.

Set up a time formatter, to parse your date/times out of your file:

```
// say date/times are local 20160622 15:00
var timeFormatter = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d %H:%M")
```

Set up a time x-scale for your axis:

```
// x scale showing 1 day - 06/22/2015
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0,width])
  .domain([timeFormatter.parse("20150621 00:00"), timeFormatter.parse("20150622 00:00")])
```

And when you draw the rect, with width is the number of pixels from endTime to startTime:

```
 g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar1")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.startTime1); // start at startTime
    })
    .attr("width", function(d,i){
      return x(d.endTime1) - x(d.startTime1); // pixel width from end to start
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.col1);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.col1);
    });
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xmkR2ttd94XCWqUIOMC9?p=preview).

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you!  Next and final query -  only having two columns on the chart (one grey, one blue). I am using one bar to represent a time period, e.g. 8:10am to 15:00pm and the other bar time 09:45 to 15:00. Can I make the width of each bar reflect the time period?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot upvote this excellent answer (not enough points).

Comment: thanks again Mark - an excellent solution that does exactly what is required.